# Fetch only one of the records with the same title in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My current query results are as follows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwda8.png)

But I want only one of the data with the same title to appear. The results I want are as follows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq3X0.png)

Thanks

Comment: I guess your response has 2 different elements in array. But you may use `.findOne`

Comment: this response was just an example. This Query an array with 40 elements can also be returned at the same time.

Comment: You might use Array.reduce()